# Working out an orbital period, given constants (earth's radius and GM) and average altitude

Tags: geometry

I am having some trouble figuring out a formula for a JavaScript coding exercise.

Given a GM of 398,600.4418, earth's radius of 6,367.4447, and an average altitude of 35,873.5553, I must return an answer of 86,400.

I have experimented with the formula shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_period#Small_body_orbiting_a_central_body) but I cannot figure out how the average altitude comes into the equation, nor how to work out SMa³.

I just need a hint or two to help me understand the formula. Many thanks.

Comment: From 2019 -> thanks, I'm also solving the freeCodeCamp challenges :)

Comment: @AlexBG Best of luck, I have been a front end dev for 3 years now after completing FCC :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the orbit is circular, then $a$ in that formula is the orbital radius, which is the sum of altitude and Earth's radius.